# Field 'permission_type' has incomplete type

Tags: c

When I try to compile one I get this error:

```
In file included from arch/arm/mach-msm/board-htcleo.c:81:0:
include/linux/ion.h:192:27: error: field 'permission_type' has incomplete type
```

How can I solve this problem?  My code is as follows:

```
struct ion_cp_heap_pdata {
    enum ion_permission_type permission_type;
    unsigned int align;
    ion_phys_addr_t secure_base; /* Base addr used when heap is shared */
    size_t secure_size; /* Size used for securing heap when heap is shared*/
    int reusable;
    int mem_is_fmem;
    enum ion_fixed_position fixed_position;
    int iommu_map_all;
    int iommu_2x_map_domain;
    ion_virt_addr_t *virt_addr;
    int (*request_region)(void *);
    int (*release_region)(void *);
    void *(*setup_region)(void);
};
```

Comment: Make sure `enum ion_permission_type` is defined before the `struct` declaration.

Comment: I'm sorry, but how to define?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `enum ion_permission_type` before declaring `permission_type`

```
enum ion_permission_type
{
    /* Enumeration values here */
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't able to find the definition of type `enum ion_permission_type`, so define it like below.

```
enum ion_permission_type { /*define your named integer constants here...*/ };
```

Comment: like: enum ion_permission_type /*permission for ion heap*/   ??

Comment: Yes, If you are not sure how to define them, please go through the below link for basics of enum [link]http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Enum.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be defined in 
kernel/arch/arm/mach-msm/include/mach/ion.h
with value

```
enum ion_permission_type {
    IPT_TYPE_MM_CARVEOUT = 0,
    IPT_TYPE_MFC_SHAREDMEM = 1,
    IPT_TYPE_MDP_WRITEBACK = 2,
};
```